# RubyMine automatically add end after typing do. How do enable this?

Tags: rubymine

Currently when I type something like this:

```
it "returns 8 milk chocolates and 1 sugar free chocolate" do
```

I have to hit enter twice in order to add the `end`. This is annoying to me. How do I enable this to just automatically add end and bring my cursor to the correct indented position after I hit enter? What can I do?

Comment: I am also interested in this, but I have the opposite problem. Whenever I press Enter at the end of a `do` line, I get an automatic `end`. I dislike auto-insertion in the editor in general, and want to disable it. How can it be done? I am using the Ruby extension in IntelliJ, which is basically the same as RubyMine (feature-wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it for me:

`Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys`

... then check `"End on blank line"`